# Using the YouTube Data API V3 – quota very quickly runs out

Tags: discord.js, youtube-data-api

I am making a discord bot using discord.js and am using the YouTube API for music commands.

However, I managed to use up all of my quota just in testing. It can load playlists, search for songs and use urls and uses ytdl-core module to download the videos. Is it normal to use this much of a quota or is something wrong. I also noticed that you cannot get an extension for your quota without having an organisation, which I do not.

Answer (score 3):

I'm running into the same problem. The YouTube Data API has a crazy low quota/limit. While the quota sounds reasonable, 10,000 queries per day, it's actually much lower. First, they count each query as 100. So take 10,000 and divide it by 100 and that's how many queries you are really allowed to make. Furthermore, they paginate their results with a maximum of 50 results (videos) per page. So in reality, YouTube will let you access data on 5,000 videos per day using the YouTube Data APIs search functionality. To confirm my math, I just checked my quota for the day. After querying the API for 10 pages of results (50 videos per page, 500 videos total) my quota/usage is listed at 1,000 out of the 10,000 allotment per day. **Essentially, the YouTube Data API is useless.**

Comment: I agree that a quota amount of 10,000 units per day is low indeed. But, let 's clarify a few things. The quota system is a cost system employed by the YouTube Data API. There's no [official doc](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/) that states that each and every API endpoint call (i.e. query) has a quota cost of *one unit*. To the contrary, the pages corresponding to API endpoints do have a section -- *Quota impact* -- that specifies that endpoint's quota cost -- which varies from endpoint to endpoint.

Comment: For example the [`Search.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) endpoint has a quota cost of 100 units (expensive), while the [`PlaylistItems.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) endpoint has a quota cost of 1 unit (cheap). Moreover, there's a [quota cost table](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost) that enables you to evaluate at a glance in advance the costs of your API queries.

Comment: I spoke to someone else about this and they said they managed to get an increase by filling out the form with their name and address instead of business info and explaining that they are not a business.